# Is "driving in turn" a real/natural phrase?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request

Two people are going on a long trip (let's say 8 hours). The first guy drives the first 4 hours, and the other one drives the remaining 4 hours. Is it then OK to say they are driving in turn?

Also, are there other "casual"/informal ways of saying/describing that above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, "driving in turn" makes sense, but it is not the common way to say this. Native speakers will be more likely to say:

> They are taking turns driving.

Answer (score 1):

Tashus is correct and the common idiomatic expression is to "take turns driving".

Other possibilities:

> **Split the driving**.  *On the long cross-country trip the two of them split the driving so that neither would fall asleep at the wheel.*
>
> **Switch/rotate drivers**.  *In order to make good time they would switch out the driver every few hours*.